# Possible to include the create schema command in pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm using `pg_dump` to export only the DDL from a database. It's working fine, however the `create schema` command is not included in the output file.

Here is what I'm using:

`pg_dump -s -c -t myschema.mytable connectionURI`

Everything works as expected, but I was expecting a `create schema myschema` command. Is there an option I'm missing?

Comment: No. If you export the entire schema (with `-n [schema]`), it will be included, but if specific tables are selected with -t, only the CREATE TABLE (& other statements that operate on the table - constraints, permissions etc) will be generated.

Comment: @AdamKG: You might post that as answer? (I tried with a combination of `-n` and `-t`, but `-t` suppresses `CREATE SCHEMA` like you stated.)